# How to view email attachments from rough email files?

Tags: email, postfix

I have all emails located at /var/qmail/mailnames/... with plenty of emails in rough formats named like  1389529783.M831523P6454V0000FSD00000000F3I0000000007198431.158132.domain.com,S=7302747

However, when i open those files, i can't see attachments like images or so. Is there any simple client to view those images/attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`munpack` from mpack package can extract MIME encoded parts of the raw message.

Comment: Great, i wish i find some app that has gui and can preview me emails from rough files too.

Answer (score 1):

You could rename/copy the files and add a `.eml` extension and open them with mozilla thunderbird afterwards. This should show attachments too.